# Android how to open camera app with grey shaded borders

Tags: android, android-camera

I need the user to take a photo using the mobile camera.

I need the camera to have a shaded grey borders so that only the part inside the box will be cropped and taken, the rest of the image should be disregarded.

is there anyway to implement this, any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by using 4 shaded grey borders on the top,bottom,left, and right sides if my desired borders.

```
 <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<View
    android:id="@+id/rectangleView"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
    />

<!--I need only the part of the Image inside this view-->
<View
    android:id="@+id/viewLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rectangleView"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rectangleView"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rectangleView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewRight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewLeft"
    />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewDown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rectangleView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewRight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewLeft"
    />
```

And to get the snippet of the photo inside the rectangle:

```
//photoByteArray is the ByteArray that holds the picture, it is retrieved from PictureCallback
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByteArray, 0, photoByteArray.length);

//because the photo is always returned in landscape orientation
//we use the Matrix to rotate it
//disregard the Matrix if u need the photo in landscape
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);

//creating the bitmap that holds the photo
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);

//scaling the bitmap for the layout width and height.
//layout is the layout that holds the Camera SurfaceView
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, layoutWidth, layoutHeight, false);

//get the desired View's Co-ordinates
int x1 = rectView.getLeft();
int y1 = rectView.getTop();
int x2 = rectView.getRight();
int y2 = rectView.getBottom();

//Create new Bitmap that contains the part inside the rectangle only
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own custom camera to do this. You can't request a custom layout from the default firmware camera via an`Intent`.

See Android Developer docs for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera